# iOS 11 is removing native facebook integration. So, applications with current facebook sdk will not work on iOS 11?

Tags: facebook, ios11

Recently, I have read that iOS 11 is dropping the native system integration with Twitter, Facebook, Flickr, and Vimeo. I have used facebook sdk for various apps which are on the store. Will they stop working with the release of iOS 11?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are using, the login with facebook is still working with beta 2

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't. The most important thing that changes is the authorization flow with the new `SFAuthenticationSession`. You should test the functionalities that rely on FB's SDK thoroughly though, to catch any API changes or bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove native code (Account Kit) and use Facebook Latest SDK. this will work.

If you have only used Account Kit for login then you have to give a new update of the app on AppStore as there is now option to login in setting in iOS 11 now.

[Ref Blog](https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/5/15743010/apple-ios-11-wwdc-2017-facebook-twitter-social-accounts-login)